# Check whether a method has been called if not call a specific method

Tags: php, oop

I'd like to call a method if no method has been called, concrete example:

file foo.php would only contains

```
$p = new Foo();
```

the fact that no method is called would trigger a specific method.

file foo.php would now contains

```
$p = new Foo();
$p->bar();
```

this would not trigger the specific method since a method is called.

The point to do that would be to display help for user who use my class when they start.

Also I was thinking to use __destruct() but I'm not too sure when destruct is called.

Comment: Is this ***really*** necessary? I imagine you'd have to significantly alter your existing code for something so trivial. Better to invest the time to write good documentation.

Comment: Just have a private boolean property that is initialised to `false` when the object is instantiated, and when any public method is called set it to `true`. In `__destruct()` check whether the property is still `false` and if it is, call your "specific method".

Comment: The amount of confusion in this post is absolutely astounding.  PHP really does something to people's brains, I swear.

Comment: @DaveRandom Wow, *good* comment Dave. Really good. +1

Comment: @Pierreten must be due to my low english + my low capacity to explain, I'll try your way DaveRandom

Comment: @DaveRandom your way works fine, only problem, I had a lot of method to edit.

Comment: Please don't clutter your code with documentation :)

Comment: @PeeHaa just a short text with a link to the doc should be ok

Comment: Yeah, but in order to do that you would have to clutter your code with stuff which doesn't need to be in there. Can't you just add a docblock?

Comment: @PeeHaa, I'll also check it, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per DaveRandoms *amazing* comment:

```
class fooby
{
    private $hasCalled=false;

    function __destruct()
    {
        if(!$this->hasCalled)
        {
            // Run whatever you want here. No method has been called.
            echo "Bazinga!";
        }
    }

    public function someFunc()
    {
        $this->hasCalled=true;
        // Have this line in EVERY function in the object.
        echo "Funky Monkey";
    }
}

$var1 = new fooby();
$var1->someFunc(); // Output: Funky Monkey
$var1 = null; // No triggered trickery.

$var2= new fooby();
$var2 = null; // Output: Bazinga!
```

Answer (score 3):

`__destruct()` is correct.

```
class Foo {

     private $method_invoked = false;

     public function bar(){
         $this->method_invoked = true;
         print 'bar';
     }

     function __destruct(){
         if(!$this->method_invoked) {
             print 'destr'; 
         }
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for downwote with no comment

Comment: There you go, now you are even - you used the same idea that DaveRandom suggested and I just posted.